# SQL Join Query to missing Some records from first table

Tags: sql-server-2014, join

I am creating a database application in SQL Server. I have 2 tables named `tblClient` (Client Table) and `tblExpEntry` (Expense Table). I want to select all Clients from `tblClient` table and show their expense from `tblExpEntry.` But I am getting records from `tblClient` only that are non-zero records in `tblExpEntry` table like I am missing 2 records that have 0 expense. I want to get them also in selected records. I am using the below query for selecting data

```
select tblClient.ProjectName, ISNULL(SUM(tblExpEntry.TotalPayment), 0) 
     AS 'Total Expense' 
FROM tblExpEntry 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblClient ON tblClient.Client_ID=tblExpEntry.Client_ID 
WHERE tblCLient.StatusID=1 
GROUP BY ProjectName
```

Comment: From looking at your question, I would've thought it should be FROM tblClient LEFT JOIN tblExpEntry - not the way you have it written

Comment: I agree with @Scott Hodgin. Either change the order of the tables or use right outer join.